# Azure AD Collaboration - Invite any e-mail

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have running an web app secured by Azure AD.
There are a few forms the user is able to share with others. We are planning to use the azure ad guest invitation API for this.
However i can not find a clear point in the documentation wheter any given e-mail address can be invited to the AD (so any user without being a user in any other tenant nor any microsoft account) or if the user always already needs to have an account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any email can be used if you are adding a Guest user (which is what the API does).

> When the user is invited, a user entity (of userType Guest) is created

So they will get an account, it will be created in that tenant.